# Display the structure of the selected table of database in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code I want to display the structure of the selected table of the database mysql.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnect.php';
echo hello;
$z=$_GET['z'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $z";
$res= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$new= array();
 $k=0;
function mysql_fetch_all($res) {
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
 $new[$i]=$row;
      $k++;

}

$num=count($new);
}
       $return[] = $row;
   }
   return $return;
}
?>
<?php
for($m=0;$m<$num;$m++){ ?>
<?php echo $new[$m][0] ?>" <?php echo $new[$m][0]; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I am using wamp server.

Comment: What is your actual error/expected behaviour?

Comment: As a beginner, now would be an excellent time to stop using PHP's long since deprecated mysql_ API, and focus on modern methods in conjunction with prepared statements.

Comment: The mysql_* extension is deprecated not present anymore in the upcoming release of php 7. [Choose a different api](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to connect to your MySQL server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to count the rows and then to use another loop for iterating over them. You can simply use a foreach($res as $singleRes) loop structure. And then simple get the $singleRes->columnName :). Check this out [mysqli_result::fetch_fields](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php)

Comment: Thanks fro the help but i want that when i select any table from any of the selected database it show the full structure of the table.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Information Schema` to get column name:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'YOUR_TBL_NAME'
```

Comment: Thanks fro the help but i want that when i select any table from any of the selected database it show the full structure of the table.

Comment: This answer still applies, just use variables as you did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPLAIN table_name
```

This column also give structure of the `table`

Comment: Thanks, actually i want that whenever i select any table from the database it show its structure.This is not for any particular table im trying to fetch the structure of all the tables of all the databases  of my server.

Comment: All the answers are ok, i guess.. Please mark the best answer, so that it helps others also